# Is there anyway that we can update the privacy of existing wall post through api?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I would like to update the privacy of the existing wall post through api.

Is there anyway to implement it?

Or is it impossible for the api to support it now?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no API to retroactively change the privacy settings of a post, it's doable in the main interface on www.facebook.com though